# Custom log not being written to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, logging

Rails has deprecated `log.auto_flushing` in 3.2. Using `file.sync` is the recommended solution.

I have a custom logger file set up by an initializer and subscribe to active support notifications that log to that logger.

The notifications are triggered by the rails app & by rake tasks which are being run with cron.

When using `log.auto_flushing = true`, everything works as expected, and the log file contains output from the rails app & the cron tasks as they run.

When I switched to `file.sync = true`, odd things happened. The first process that opens the log can write to it, but as soon as another process starts, nothing else gets logged. The log file is not written to until it is rotated by newsyslog, at which point the first process is able to log a few lines before it is stopped.

I have two questions:

- Is `config/initializers` the correct place to be setting up a custom log?
- Is there something I need to do to allow multiple process to access the same file?

For reference, here is my [config/notifications.rb](https://gist.github.com/BM5k/5367277.js), with both configurations.